# Is copying of compiled files safe

Tags: compilation, compiler-optimization

I has a question regarding compiling sources on MSys2. I want to compile Tcl/Tk e.g. to destination C:\tcltk86. After that I want make it possible for others to copy these file on another destination through a perl module.

I am not very familiar with compiling stuff and so I wanted to ask whether it is safe just to copy compiled files. Does the system then find all files. The files will be copied to a destination in the LIBS Path so for libraries files I have no concerns. But there are possibility other files e.g. images etc.

Sorry for the very general question. But I hope you can boost my general understanding for compiling things.

Comment: It depends — that most evasive and unhelpful of answers.  In general, you can copy object files from MachineA to another machine, MachineB, as long as the two machines are sufficiently similar — running near enough the same o/s on the same architecture.  However, you might have compiled pathname information into the object file on MachineA that refers to materials stored in a different location on MachineB.  Then there'll be problems.  Ideally, that location should be defaulted but configurable.  Or you insist that MachineB matches MachineA in these critical details.

Comment: "compiled files" are often dependent on the environment (architecture, shared libs, absolute paths e.t.c). So a *general* answer would be *No*. But often you can compile it statically into some portable executable removing some of these dependencies.

Comment: Are you going to use it in a Perl module? If so, please amend that to the question.

Comment: The C tag is not about DOS drive `C`!

Comment: Thanks for your answers
@Jonathan Leffler: How can I avoid to compile pathname information into the object or how can I make the location configurable? I compile using `./configure --prefix=c:/tcltk86 --enable-64bit --enable-threads --enable-shared && make && make install`
@Eugene: What does it mean

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sh. Sh.: What does it mean to compule it statically and how can I do this?

Comment: @a3f: The perl modul shall only copy the files to the right location in the Strawberry Perl distribution. The question concerns the following bug: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=71535

Comment: The `--prefix` option more or less hardwires that directory into the compiled code.  That means you'll have to go with the 'machineB must look enough like machineA' option — specifically, they'll have to use `c:\tcltk86` as the directory on machineB.  Now, if someone already has their own copy already installed there, they may not be happy with you.  Unless they have their own copy already installed there, they should be OK with it.  If they're unwilling to yield, you'll need to reconsider the location and rebuild. (Eugene's comment means that it is hard to avoid 'machine B must look like A').

Comment: oh shit :-) The problem is that I don't know where the Strawberry files on machineB are. Usually it is C:\Strawberry and the files shall be copied into C:\Strawberry\perl\site. But users can install Strawberry into every directory they want.. That means my problem at the compiling stage is, I don't know where the files will be on machineB. But they must be in a directory where perl can find them...